# CiviDiscount advanced filter not working

Tags: wordpress, cividiscount

I've installed the CiviDiscount ext for CiviCRM 5.67.0.
CiviDiscount is at 3.8.8.

When i apply the Advanced filter for autodiscount i apply The following:

1. Specify entity for advanced autodiscount: "Contact".
2. Specify api string for advanced filter: "{"id":"110"}".

But when i load the contribution page the automatic discount isn't applied.